# Stopping OrientDB service fails, ETL import not possible

Tags: docker, orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb-etl

My goal is to import data from CSV-files into OrientDB.
I use the `OrientDB 2.2.22` Docker image.
When I try to execute the `/orientdb/bin/oetl.sh config.json` script within Docker, I get the error: `"Can not open storage it is acquired by other process"`.

I guess this is, because the OrientDB - service is still running. But, if I try to stop it i get the next error.

```
./orientdb.sh stop
./orientdb.sh: return: line 70: Illegal number: root
```

or

```
./orientdb.sh status
./orientdb.sh: return: line 89: Illegal number: root
```

The only way for to use the `./oetl.sh` script is to stop the Docker instance and restart it in the interactive mode running the shell, but this is awkward because to use the "OrientDB Studio" I have to stop docker again and start it in the normal mode.

Comment: Point your etl to the server instead of using plocal, e.g : remote:server/dbname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Roberto Franchini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/789431/roberto-franchini) mentioned above setting the `dbURL` parameter in the [Loader](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Loader.html) to use a `remote` URL fixed the first issue `"Can not open storage it is acquired by other process"`.

The issues with the `.orientdb.sh` still exists, but with the remote-URL approach I don't need to shutdown and restart the service anymore.

Comment: Well, if you work with docker and containers in general, you should not start and stop services inside the container, but the container itself.